# DMZ vs Port Forwarding

Tags: security, firewall, port, forwarding, dmz

We're a medium sized company and working with a vendor who requires us to set up a server. The connection to this server is from a list of fixed IP addresses in the cloud. They have only required the inbound communication to be through HTTPS, and are not willing to support us if we put this server on the DMZ. I'd like to be able  to inspect this traffic through a firewall at the least. I'm aware that outside facing servers should be put in a DMZ, but I'm not sure if similar practice is followed for traffic originating from a list of fixed IP addresses (cz source IPs can be spoofed too).